# iOS - iAd Banners not appearing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Ok so I integrated an iAd banner within my app using the `iAd` framework and the `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` approach, however now that my app has been accepted, when downloading the final release version from the store, no banner ads are shown. Is there anything I need to do on the iTunes Connect end to fill the banners with content? Or is it just a dodgy fill rate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple are discontinuing the iAd services, an email to that effect was sent out in May"

> You are receiving this email because you entered into the Developer Advertising Services Agreement (“Agreement”) to use iAd’s advertising network and related services. We would like to thank you for allowing Apple to serve ads on your mobile properties. As you may know, the iAd App Network and related advertising services will be discontinued on June 30, 2016. More details about the iAd App Network shutdown are here. Note: Any outstanding payments due from Apple will be made no later than September 30, 2016, and campaign reporting data will be available until December 31, 2016.
>
> This email shall serve as written notice that Apple will exercise its option to terminate the Agreement, effective June 30, 2016, 11:59 pm PDT. Nothing contained in, or omitted from, this notice shall be deemed a waiver of any of Apple’s rights, remedies or defenses, all of which are expressly reserved.
> "

Comment: I understand that it is shutting down however it also says that ads should be served up until the 30th June.

Comment: I am guessing that no new apps are being accepted then?

Comment: I think that whether or not they work, they shouldn't be implemented in anything being submitted to the app store and it's a waste of time trying to carry out any development with them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've decided to go with ad mob and have it working properly now :)